# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) libpam0g:amd64

Tags: apt

After installing a Bluetooth driver, the following error is shown, I have tried everything without any success. Following is the log that it shows when I try to fix it.

```
esar@cesar-P43E:~$ sudo apt install --fix-broken
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/55.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package libpam0g:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam0g:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this?

I have tried the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall liblmdb0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/100 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package libpam0g:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam0g:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
$ sudo apt --purge remove liblmdb0:amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libpam0g needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libpam0g needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

`sudo apt-get update`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a` returned no error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libpam0g needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

```
$ sudo apt remove libpam0g
[sudo] password for cesar: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libpam0g needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I really do not know what to do in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1343902/edit) your question and give us specifics of what you have tried so that we are not guessing or giving you something to try that you already did.  Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Some versions contain liblmdb0 in universe while some in main. Probably that is missing from software sources configured.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Hi Kully, I followed one the steps you suggested on the link you provided:I had a situation worse than this. I had to remove the half-installed packages by forcing dependencies.
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --force-depends <package-name>
Then I had to reinstall them
sudo apt-get -f install. It worked and it looks to solve the problem, but it indicated that I had problems with grup-pc so I remove it, now I cannot enter on my windows partition. Can you help?

Comment: @CesarA.Williams Please post a new question with full error logs and the commands you used.